# Collision point of two vehicles with constant velocity

Tags: physics

Given the constanct velocities of two vehicles that are on a frontal collison line and their distance from each other:

How can I calculate the collision point?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it just $(v_1+v_2)t=d$ so $t={d\over v_1+v_2}$ and collision $c=v_1t+c_0={v_1d\over v_1+v_2} + c_0$ where $c_0$ is the initial position of first vehicle?